# Bulk editing in MUI X PRO

Tags: material-ui, mui-x-data-grid, mui-x

Is there a working example of bulk editing in MUI X PRO version? I tried using the same example as MUI X Premium by changing imports to Pro, but Pro version does not support "unstable_cellSelection" and "experimentalFeatures={{ clipboardPaste: true }}" props. When tried using bulk editing without these props, unable to write anything while editing.

When tried using bulk editing without "unstable_cellSelection" and "experimentalFeatures={{ clipboardPaste: true }}" props, unable to write anything while editing.